# Get element which does not have certain ancestor with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have HTML containing something like:

```html
<div class="ignore">
  <span>ignore me</span>
</div>
<span>get me</span>
```

(This is a simplified example.)

Using beautifulsoup, how do I go about getting the `span`s that do not have an ancestor with class `ignore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select all of the `span` elements and then filter them by checking to see if they have parent elements with the class `ignore`.

In the example below, the `.select()` method selects all the span elements and then the conditional statement filters out the elements where `.find_parents()` returns an element with the class `ignore`:

```
for element in soup.select('span'):
  if not element.find_parents(attrs={"class": "ignore"}):
    # This element doesn't have an ancestor with class 'ignore'
    print(element.text)
```

And if you just want the list of the elements directly [(example here)](https://repl.it/F2Pi/1):

```
spans = [e for e in soup.select('span') if not e.find_parents(attrs={"class": "ignore"})]
for span in spans:
  print(span.text)
```